# How to get vertex using vertex property for Java application?

Tags: java, gremlin, graph-databases, tinkerpop, janusgraph

We have a User.java class.

```
public class User{
 

    private String name;
    private List<String> phone;

   //setters and getters
}
```

Inside this one node created

```
{
   "name": "Ibney",
   "phone": ["123","704","456"]
}
```

now I want to get User vertex using phone. I have provide list of phone numbers but different one and one of the string 704 is matched.
How to get user vertex. Using any
I'm using like this

```
List<String> phone = new ArrayList<>();
phone.add("204");
phone.add("704");

List<Vertex> vertex = g.V().hasLabel(label.getLabel()).has(phone, P.within(phone)).toList();
```

match value is 704 but unfortunately this is not working.

Comment: Did you create that list using meta properties (three `property` steps) or did you just store a Java list into the property?

Comment: @KelvinLawrence this is just an example. I'm passing List<String> phone in method parameter.

Comment: I added an answer below that explains what you are seeing.

Answer (score 1):

If you are storing the property as an actual Java List the `within` step will not look inside that. You need to `unfold` it. Along the lines of:

```
gremlin> phone = ["123","704","456"] 
gremlin> g.addV('test').property('phone',phone)  

==>v[60867]

gremlin> g.V().has('phone').where(values('phone').unfold().is(within(phone)))

==>v[60867]
```

However, not all DBs support storing Java types like a List directly. To get more flexibility you may want to create your list using.

```
gremlin> g.addV('test').
......1>       property(list,'phone',"123"). 
......2>       property(list,'phone',"704"). 
......3>       property(list,'phone',"456")

==>v[60869]

gremlin> g.V().has('phone',within(phone))

==>v[60869]
```

Comment: I think it will not work in java? I think some problem are there. It is not perfect answer for me.
thank you Sir

Comment: Why do you say it will not work in Java ? - I do the above all the time in Java